# How to compute the rate of the quotien of two counters with PromQL?

Tags: prometheus, promql

I have two metrics with labels (name, node)

- `query_latency_milliseconds_sum`: sum of execution times of queries
- `query_latency_milliseconds_count`: sum of number of queries

To have the mean response time by query, I do:

```
sum by (name) (increase(query_latency_milliseconds_sum[10m])) / 
sum by (name) (increase(query_latency_milliseconds_count[10m]))
```

Now I want to put an alert when this value increase too much.

I started writing:

```
rate(
    sum by (name) (increase(query_latency_milliseconds_sum[10m])) /
    sum by (name) (increase(query_latency_milliseconds_count[10m]))
)
```

But I get the error:

> "parse error: expected type range vector in call to function "rate", got instant vector"

With

```
rate(
  sum by (name) (increase(query_latency_milliseconds_sum[10m])) / 
  sum by (name) (increase(query_latency_milliseconds_count[10m]))
[10m])
```

I get the error:

> "parse error: ranges only allowed for vector selectors"

And with:

```
rate(
  sum by (name) (increase(query_latency_milliseconds_sum)) /
  sum by (name) (increase(query_latency_milliseconds_count))
[10m])
```

I get the error:

> "parse error: ranges only allowed for vector selectors"

What am I doing wrong? Is what I want doable with PromQL or should I create an intermediate metric for this?

Comment: If I understood your problem (`when this value increases too much`) you actually don't need to use the `rate` function. Just create an alert that is based on `YOUR_FORMULA` > `YOUR_THRESHOLD`